# How to get portal preferences setting from table on Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I am a Liferay user, I need to get some of properties in my liferay portal, such as dl.file.max.size,users.image.max.size... in portal preferences table. Everything setting with key instead add to portal-ext.properties.

And how to update back changed value?

I tried some code

```
PortalPreferences portalPreferences = PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortalPreferences(request);

long usersImageMaxSize = GetterUtil.getLong(portalPreferences.getValue(PropsKeys.USERS_IMAGE_MAX_SIZE,"0"),0);
```

but get nothing.

Please help!.

Thanks advance.

(Liferay portal 6.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong code. PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil is not the right util class (it's for portlet preferences).

Instead you have to use this code:

```
long usersImageMaxSize = GetterUtil.getLong(PropsUtil.get(PropsKeys.USERS_IMAGE_MAX_SIZE));
```

Comment: Thanks you but that code just get a default value, not value can change in control panel.

Comment: Yes, if you want the value overridden by control panel and saved to database use the `PrefsPropsUtil.get`

Comment: So which api used to update, override value of control panel?

Comment: can you write a example ? i dont see PrefsPropsUtil has set and update

Answer (score 2):

I found result. Here code example:

```
        PortletPreferences portletPreferences = PrefsPropsUtil.getPreferences();

        String value= portletPreferences.getValue(PropsKeys.DL_FILE_MAX_SIZE, "0");

        System.out.println(value);


        portletPreferences.setValue(PropsKeys.DL_FILE_MAX_SIZE,"123456789") 
        portletPreferences.store();

        value = portletPreferences.getValue(PropsKeys.DL_FILE_MAX_SIZE, "0");

        System.out.println(value);
```

Thanks Daniele for help.